# Converting user supplied strings to numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, numbers

I know this is a very basic question, but I'm having trouble finding the standard / best way to do this in a rails app. This seems like a pretty typical problem, I'm sure there is an elegant way to solve this.

Here's the problem. I have a Client model with an "estimated_worth" decimal column:

```
client = Client.new
client.estimated_worth = "2,000"
client.estimated_worth
=> 2
```

Obviously this is not good. I also see this sometimes:

```
client = Client.new
client.estimated_worth = "2 thousand"
client.estimated_worth
=> 2
```

Is there a nice way to handle this in rails that I am missing? Basically, I'm looking for something similar to Time.parse() but for numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any definite Rails methods for this, but personally I'd validate the input on the clientside form using JavaScript - a simple regex would do:

```
 ^\d+$
```

, or you could use something like http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation if you prefer - and then do some validation in the model to confirm.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, just seems so un-user-friendly. I have to imagine there is an elegant solution for handling user supplied numbers. That seems much more rubyish.

Comment: Oh yeah, there's probably a more rubyesque way of doing it, but given you're validating user input, the logical place to do it in my mind would be on the form itself. What if for example, a user entered 2.000 expecting that to be taken as two thousand. How would you handle that as integer versus a float? What if someone entered 2000.50? You can sidestep all of that by just filtering out non-numeric text before it hits your application.. I'm not sure what you mean by user-un-friendly though?

Comment: No, I think you're suggestion is good and probably what I'll end up doing. I just like to make the process as smooth as possible. Nothing is more annoying than filling out a form and then having to correct a value that is technically correct. Ex: when a website wants my phone number in a specific format. I want to try and avoid that if possible.